# adding to multiindexed pandas dataframe by specific indices is incredibly slow

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, pandas-loc

I have a rather large data frame (~400M rows).  For each row, I calculate which elements in another data frame (~200M rows) I need to increment by 1.  This second data frame is indexed by three parameters.  So the line I use to do this looks like:

```
total_counts[i].loc[zipcode,j,g_durs[j][0]:g_durs[j][-1]+1] += 1
```

The above line works, but it appears to be a horrendous bottleneck and takes almost 1 second to run.  Unfortunately, I cannot wait 11 years for this to finish.

Any insights on how I might speed up this operation?  Do I need to split up the 200M row data frame into an array of smaller objects?  I don't understand exactly what is making this so slow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @rpanai, and thanks for responding.  The entire bottleneck is due to the single line I included above, which does nothing but index a large multi-indexed data frame.  You want me to add code for constructing an example of such a data frame?  What exactly is missing from this question?  Anyway, I think I found a solution, so I will update the question with both after I finish testing.  Thanks.

Comment: What are i and j?  Is this in some sort of for loop?